# Edge-disjoint paths in $k$-regular graphs

Tags: graph-theory

Is it correct to assume that every $k$-regular graph has at least $k$ edge-disjoint paths for every pair of vertices? If so, how could someone prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is false. Most obviously, you have not required that the graph be connected, so there may not be *any* paths between two given vertices.  But even for connected graphs it is false.  Consider a graph of the following type:

[image]

Suppose that the blue blobs are such that the entire graph is 3-regular.  But between a vertex in blob $A$ and a vertex in blob $B$ there can be at most one edge-disjoint path.

Comment: yes but can such a graph be built? How could one blob have one vertex of degree 1 and all other with degree equal to $k$?

Comment: @SotirisKal, yes it can be built, just take a blob to be any $3$-regular graph, subdivide a single edge and connect that new vertex to $v$.